# Custom Width and blank space for angular material autocomplete

Tags: angularjs, material-design, livesearch

I want to make a live search and I want to use the "md-autocomplete" from angular material. My problem is that I don't know how to set a custom width to it.

Another problem is that I have a lot of white space in my search, for example:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: I've done [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/The_Bear/tzmcj2n5/7/) with your problem.The custom with is easy to set if you override the `md-autocomplete` class. And about the white space, I think that you probably had problems in your filter function. Share a little bit more of your controller code or try to update the jsFiddle.

Comment: Thanks for your response. That help me with the blank space, but also I can't modify the width, any suggestion?

Comment: `md-autocomplete {width: 250px;}` [JSFIDDLE UPDATED](https://jsfiddle.net/tzmcj2n5/10/)

Comment: Thanks, it works.